# Angular js filter search not working in IE 11 and Edge, why?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, internet-explorer

I used angular js search filter and php, it works fine in Mozilla and chrome, but not at all work in IE 11 , Edge, IE versions, some pls guide me, below code iam using,

manageusers.php

```
<div class="loading-dialog" ng-show="imLoading"></div>
<html ng-app="myAppMembers" ng-app lang="en">
<div ng-controller="customersCrtl">
<div class="content" ng-cloak>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">PageSize:
            <select ng-model="entryLimit" class="form-control">
                <option>5</option>
                <option>10</option>
                <option>20</option>
                <option>50</option>
                <option>100</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">Filter:
            <input type="text" ng-model="search" ng-change="filter()" placeholder="Filter" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h5>Filtered {{ filtered.length }} Of {{ totalItems}} Total Users</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" ng-show="filteredItems > 0">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
            <th>Id&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('id');"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></i></a></th>
            <th>User Name<a ng-click="sort_by('newusername');"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></i></a></th>
            <th>Email<a ng-click="sort_by('email');"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></i></a></th>
            <th>Last Login<a ng-click="sort_by('newlastlogin');"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></i></a></th>


            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | filter:search | orderBy : predicate :reverse) | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit">
                   <td>{{data.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.newusername}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.email}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.newlastlogin}}</td>

                </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12" ng-show="filteredItems == 0">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h4>No Users Found</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12" ng-show="filteredItems > 0">    
            <div pagination="" page="currentPage" on-select-page="setPage(page)" boundary-links="true" total-items="filteredItems" items-per-page="entryLimit" class="pagination-small" previous-text="&laquo;" next-text="&raquo;"></div>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>/angular/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>/angular/js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>/angular/app/getadminmembers.js"></script>

</html>
```

getadminmembers.js

```
var app = angular.module('myAppMembers', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.filter('startFrom', function() {                             
   return function(input, start) {
        if(input) {
            start = +start; //parse to int
            return input.slice(start);
        }
        return [];
    }
});
app.controller('customersCrtl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
$http.get('www.testurl.com/index.php/admin/default/getmembers').success(function(data){                                                                                                                                                                 //alert("testtttt");

        $scope.list = data;
        $scope.currentPage = 1; //current page
        $scope.entryLimit = 20; //max no of items to display in a page
        $scope.filteredItems = $scope.list.length; //Initially for no filter  
        $scope.totalItems = $scope.list.length;
    });
    $scope.setPage = function(pageNo) {
        $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
    };
    $scope.filter = function() {
        $timeout(function() { 
            $scope.filteredItems = $scope.filtered.length;
        }, 10);
    };
    $scope.sort_by = function(predicate) {
        $scope.predicate = predicate;
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
    };
});
```